# The code's if statement has a logic error and I do not know how to fix it

Tags: if-statement, logic, card

I am writing a code, to create two card object with character "rank""suit""pointvalue" and the method matches is aim to compare each of the character. But now I got a problem that no matter what character I give to the two object the code will always gives the result that they are the same. There must be some logical error, what should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay4S9.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the method when getting suit/rank for the card object.

You might want to know when and when not use `static`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-non-static-method-in-java/